# Subsetting Pandas dataframe via column number

Tags: python, pandas

When I want to retrieve the jth+1 value from the column of a panda dataframe, I can write: `df["column_name"].ix[j]`

When I check the type of the above code, I get:

```
type(df["column_name"].ix[i]) #str
```

I want to write less lengthy code though subsetting by the index. So I write: 
`df[[i]].ix[j]`

However, when I check the type, I get: `pandas.core.series.Series`

How I rewrite this for the indexical subsetting to produce a `str`?

Answer (score 2):

The double subscripting does something else than what you seem to imply it does - it returns a *DataFrame* of the corresponding columns.

As far as I know, the shortest way to do what you're asking using column-row ordering is

```
df.iloc[:, j].ix[i]
```

(There's the shorter

```
df.icol(j).ix[i]
```

but it's deprecated.)

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is like so:

```
df.ix[i][j]
```

This is kind of funky though, because the first index is the row, and the second is the column, which is rather not pandas.  More like matrix indexing than pandas indexing.